# Entity Framework Getting current date rows(while time in that day)

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have table that the value of dateime is like this

```
2021-12-08 10:10:54.657
2021-12-08 10:10:41.567
2021-12-08 10:09:51.960
2021-12-08 10:10:54.657
2021-12-08 10:10:41.567
2021-12-08 10:09:51.960
2021-12-08 10:10:54.657
```

and I want to get that day or today (now is 8 dec 2021) . So i have tried using EF in controller :

```
 ViewBag.CByUserToday = _db.ArrayDatas.Where(a => a.CreatedBy == user && a.CreatedDate == DateTime.Today.Date).Count();
```

But i still did not get the rows. When i tried to debug DateTime.Today.Date , it's said DateTime.Today = {09/12/2021 00:00:00} . But when i tried to update that createddate to '2021-12-09 00:00:00.000' it can be retrieved.
So, how to retrieve that rows that i have created today(ignoring the time) ?

Comment: Use `>` and `<`.

Answer (score 2):

Check that the column is greater than or equal to today, and less than tomorrow:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime tomorrow = today.AddDays(1);
ViewBag.CByUserToday = _db.ArrayDatas
    .Where(a => a.CreatedBy == user 
             && a.CreatedDate >= today 
             && a.CreatedDate < tomorrow)
    .Count();
```

That way, your DBMS will be able to use a suitable index on the `CreatedBy` and `CreatedDate` columns to satisfy your query.

It's usually preferable to avoid calling functions on a column when you're trying to filter it, since this means the query is not [SARGable](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162263/what-does-the-word-sargable-really-mean). However, according to [this thread on DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea), casting a `datetime`/`datetime2` column to `date` *is* SARGable, at least in Microsoft SQL Server.